# How to remove directory from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to remove directory from URL. I have a page in `mydomain.com/dir/` and all links works under `mydomain.com/dir/link1.html`, `mydomain.com/dir/link2.html` etc.

I would like to create single URL which will be `mydomain.com/new_link` and will trace to `mydomain.com/dir/index.php?page=13`. I would like it to do only once, for one link, not a regular expression. .htaccess file is located in `dir` directory with the following content:

```
RewriteRule ^new_link$ index.php?page=13 [L]
```

But this causes that the `dir` is still visible.

Answer (score 1):

I do not entirely understand your question. From  what I have understood,

if you want to remove `dir` from your URL, have your `.htaccess` in parent directory of `dir`. I think its the DocumentRoot in your case.

And add this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^new_link$ dir/index.php?page=13 [QSA,L]
```